# How to parse mathematical expressions involving parentheses

Tags: .net, math, parsing

This isn't a school assignment or anything, but I realize it's a mostly academic question.  But, what I've been struggling to do is parse 'math' text and come up with an answer.

For Example - I can figure out how to parse '5 + 5' or '3 * 5' - but I fail when I try to correctly chain operations together.

(5 + 5) * 3

It's mostly just bugging me that I can't figure it out.  If anyone can point me in a direction, I'd really appreciate it.

**EDIT**
Thanks for all of the quick responses.  I'm sorry I didn't do a better job of explaining.

First - I'm not using regular expressions.  I also know there are already libraries available that will take, as a string, a mathematical expression and return the correct value.  So, I'm mostly looking at this because, sadly, I don't "get it".

Second - What I've tried doing (is probably misguided) but I was counting '(' and ')' and evaluating the deepest items first.  In simple examples, this worked; but my code is not pretty and more complicated stuff crashes.  When I 'calculated' the lowest level, I was modifying the string.

So...
(5 + 5) * 3

Would turn into
10 * 3

Which would then evaluate to 
30

But it just felt 'wrong'.

I hope that helps clarify things.  I'll certainly check out the links provided.

Comment: Are you using regular expressions?  How are you currently parsing the text?

Comment: The Dragon Book. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science) is an excellent introduction to these types of things.

Comment: More specifically, what have you tried and why doesn't it work?  SO works best on specifics, and you're likely to get a better answer when you post more details.

Comment: Ronald Mak's book - Writing Compilers and Interpreters. http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Compilers-Interpreters-Ronald-Mak/dp/0471113530 is also a great resource.

Comment: Possibly helpful thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081/parsing-where-can-i-learn-about-it

Comment: Take your pick, [Code Golf: Mathematical expression evaluator (that respects PEMDAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384811/code-golf-mathematical-expression-evaluator-full-pemdas)

Comment: This is by no means an 'academic' question - parsing expressions is a core problem in Computer Science and Software Engineering.

Comment: @Arrieta - I think Rob P. means that he understands it is a "solved" problem, just that he was stuck understanding it. Hopefully he has found his answer an can now mark this question as "answered".

Comment: @Rob, for a simple language like this you can actually use a single regular expression for your Lexer/Scanner/Tokenizer: e.g. "(-?[0-9]+|[*+-\/\(\)])". What the regex will not do is bracket/parenthesis matching. For that you should use one of the other techniques (Shunting Yard/ recursive descent)

Comment: Here is a good math-parser: https://github.com/scicave/math-parser

Comment: Here is a good parser for math expressions written in latex: https://github.com/scicave/math-latex-parser

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ages ago when working on a simple graphing app, I used [the shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) (which is reasonably easy to understand and works great for simple math expressions like these) to first turn the expression into [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and then calculated the result. RPN was nice and fast to execute for different variable values.

Of course, language parsing is a very wide topic and there are many other ways of going about it (and pre-made tools for it too)

Comment: This is a great idea for a small calculator parser and it can be implemented fast. but it can also get quite hairy fast if you want to do slightly more complex stuff like function calls (`sin`,`cos`)

Comment: @shoosh: Actually, function calls could quite easily be implemented as unary operators (although the Wikipedia page seems to ignore them, the algorithm can be extended to take them into account). For multiple parameters, you could introduce a binary comma operator that packs values together.

Comment: ~ What math calls would have multiple parameters inside a paren besides maybe higher order math? If you're doing a parser on stuff with multiple dimensions, something tells me you've already done a simpler parser... also, (in simple terms) `sin( VALUE )` & `VALUE ::= [paren-open] term [operator term] [paren-close]` no?

Comment: you're right ofcourse. The shit really hits the fan though when you want the same function name to be overloaded to take either one or two parameters.

Comment: @shoosh: Nah, if you consider `f(x, y)` to be f applied to a single argument, that is `(x, y)`, then you'll be fine. You could see this argument as a tuple, created by the `,` operator (as Matti alluded to).

Answer (score 10):

@Rising Star
[I hoped to add this as a comment, but the formatting failed]

It may seem counterintuitive, but a binary tree is both simpler and more flexible. A node, in this case, would be either a constant (number) or an operator. A binary tree makes life somewhat easier when you decide to extend the language with elements like control flow, and functions.

Example:

```
((3 + 4 - 1) * 5 + 6 * -7) / 2

                  '/'
                /     \
              +        2
           /     \
         *         *
       /   \     /   \
      -     5   6     -7
    /   \
   +     1
 /   \
3     4
```

In the case above the scanner has been programmed to read '-' followed by a series of digits as a single number, so "-7" gets returned as the value component of the "number" token. '-' followed by whitespace is retured as a "minus" token. This makes the parser somewhat easier to write. It fails on the case where you want "-(x * y)", but you can easily change the expression to "0 - exp"

Comment: A simple application of the composite pattern will see inner (composite) nodes as "BinaryOperator" and leaf nodes as "Constant". This is of course no longer strictly speaking a binary tree.

Comment: I have to correct myself: "-" immediatly followed by "[0-9]" becomes a number, any other instance of "-" is returned as the MINUS token. A simple RegEx that returns a stream of "tokens" would be: "(-?[0-9]+|[*+-/()]|[a-z][a-z0-9]+|<=|>=|<|>|=)". this handles identifiers and relational operators. It treats unspecified lexemes as whitespace.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple (naive operator precedence) grammar for what you want.

```
expression = 
    term
    | expression "+" term
    | expression "-" term .
term = 
    factor
    | term "*" factor
    | term "/" factor .
factor = 
    number
    | "(" expression ")" .
```

When you process "factor" you just check whether the next token is a number or "(", if it's a "(" then you parse "expression" again, when **expression** returns you check if the next token is ")". You could have the [calculated|read] values bubble up to the parent through the use of **out** or **ref** parameters, or build an expression tree.

Here is the same thing in EBNF:

```
expression = 
    term
    { "+" term | "-" term  } .

term = 
    factor
    { "*" factor | "/" factor }.

factor = 
    number
    | "(" expression ")" .
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone seeing this question nine years into the future from when this post was made: If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, there are many exotic math parsers out there.

There is one that I wrote years ago in Java, which supports arithmetic operations, equation solving, differential calculus, integral calculus, basic statistics, function/formula definition, graphing, etc.

Its called [ParserNG](https://github.com/gbenroscience/ParserNG) and its free.

Evaluating an expression is as simple as:

```
    MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("(34+32)-44/(8+9(3+2))-22"); 
    System.out.println("result: " + expr.solve());

    result: 43.16981132075472
```

Or using variables and calculating simple expressions:

```
 MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("r=3;P=2*pi*r;"); 
System.out.println("result: " + expr.getValue("P"));
```

Or using functions:

```
MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("f(x)=39*sin(x^2)+x^3*cos(x);f(3)"); 
System.out.println("result: " + expr.solve());

result: -10.65717648378352
```

Or to evaluate the derivative at a given point(**NOTE:** *It does symbolic differentiation(not numerical) behind the scenes, so the accuracy is not limited by the errors of numerical approximations*):

```
MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("f(x)=x^3*ln(x); diff(f,3,1)"); 
System.out.println("result: " + expr.solve());

 result: 38.66253179403897
```

Which differentiates **`x^3 * ln(x)`** once at x=3.
The number of times you can differentiate is 1 for now.

or for Numerical Integration:

```
MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("f(x)=2*x; intg(f,1,3)"); 
System.out.println("result: " + expr.solve());

result: 7.999999999998261... approx: 8
```

This parser is decently fast and has lots of other functionality.

**DISCLAIMER: ParserNG is authored by me.**

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever take a class on formal languages in school? Effectively you need a grammar to parse by.

EDIT: Oh crap, Wikipedia says I'm wrong, but now I forget the correct name :( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar

Comment: Infix notation needs a grammar.  Postfix (RPN) can be parsed with a push-down automata which is much easier to implement than a grammar.

Comment: Be careful not no equate (formal) grammar with context-free grammar. A regular language is also generated by a grammar, a regular one.

Comment: @anno ~ aren't the basic math ops pretty well able to be described by a formal grammar? But yes, it was context-free that I was thinking initially, along with automata.

Answer (score 2):

Last year-ish I wrote a basic math evaluator for reasons I can't remember. It is not in any way a "proper" parser by any stretch of the term, and .. like all old code, I'm not that proud of it now.

But [you can take a look](http://74.207.233.86/woogley.net/misc/MathEval/MathEval.java) and see if it helps you.

You run some input tests by launching this [standalone Java app](http://74.207.233.86/woogley.net/misc/MathEval/Test.jar)

Answer (score 2):

When I wanted to parse something I decided to use the GOLD Parser:

- Self-contained documentation (don't need a book to understand it)
- Various run-time engines, in various programming languages including the one I wanted.

The parser includes [sample grammars](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/grammars/index.htm), including e.g. one for operator prcedence.

---

Apart from GOLD are also other more famous parsers, e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org), which I haven't used.

Answer (score 2):

As many answers have already stated, the issue is that you need a `recursive parser` with `associativity rules` because you can end up with expressions like:

```
val = (2-(2+4+(3-2)))/(2+1)*(2-1)
```

and your parser needs to know that:

1. The parenthetic expressions are evaluated from the inside out
2. The division takes precedence over multiplication (you first divide, then multiply the result)
3. The multiplication takes precedence over addition/subtraction

As you can imagine, writing a (good) parser is an art. The good thing is that there are several tools, called `parser generators` which allow you to easily define the *grammar* of your language, and the *parsing rules*. You may want to check the entries in Wikipedia for *BNF*, so that you can see how a grammar is defined.

Finally, if you are doing this for learning experience, go ahead. If this is for production code, do not reinvent the wheel, and find an existing library, otherwise you risk spending 1000 lines of code to add 2+2.

Comment: I agree with points 1 & 2, but 3 seems unnecessary because division is the same as multiplying with the reciprocal (multiplicative inverse) [i.e. a / b = a * 1/b], and multiplication is associative [(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)] and commutative [a * b = b * a]. These properties, alongside the distributive property [a * (b + c) = (a * b) + (a * c)], are often used to optimize an expression.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake in my comment: I agree that 
1.The parenthetic expressions are evaluated from the inside out 
3.The multiplication takes precedence over addition/subtraction 
It is with the 2nd item that I disagree (division takes precedence over multiplication)

Comment: @Andre: but if division does not take precendence over multiplication, how would you do this: 6/2*4? How can you multiply by four something that you don't have the value for? Isn't it true that you first get the value 6/2 = 3, and then 3*4 = 12? As you mention, that "division is the same as multiplying by the inverse", in order to have the inverse you MUST have divided (otherwise, where is the inverse?)

Comment: I think the term "precedence" is not correct, though, as they have the same "operator precedence", maybe it is "associativity"?

Comment: @Arrieta: You are right, this is normally resolved by associativity: the PLUS, MINUS, MUL, and DIV operators are normally left associative. Thus 6/2*4 is essencially parsed as if it was (6/2)*4; 4*6/2 is parsed as (4*6)/2. If you define "^" as a exponent operator then use right association (recursion) e.g. 2^3^4 --> 2^(3^4).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are asking us how to write a "parser."  Here is another Stack Overflow question about parsers:  [hand coding a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632641/hand-coding-a-parser/2632680#2632680)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to what you describe.  I use recursion to parse all the parenthesis.  I then use a ternary tree to represent the different segments.  The left branch is the left hand side of the operator.  The center branch is the operator.  The right branch is the right hand side of the operator.

**Short Answer** Recursion and ternary trees.

Answer (score 1):

There is always an option to use math parser library, such as [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/). You can:

**1 - Check expression syntax**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("2+3-");
e.checkSyntax();
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getErrorMessage());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] [2+3-] checking ...
[2+3-] lexical error 

Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 4.
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <UNIT> ...
    "~" ...
    "@~" ...
    <NUMBER_CONSTANT> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <FUNCTION> ...
    "[" ...

[2+3-] errors were found.
```

[mXparser-v.4.0.0]

**2 - Evaluate expression**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("2+3-(10+2)");
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] 2+3-(10+2) = -7.0
```

**3 - Use built-in functions constants, operators, etc..**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("sin(pi)+e");
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] sin(pi)+e = 2.718281828459045
```

**4 - Define your own functions, arguments and constants**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument z = new Argument("z = 10");
Constant a = new Constant("b = 2");
Function p = new Function("p(a,h) = a*h/2");
Expression e = new Expression("p(10, 2)-z*b/2", p, z, a);
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] p(10, 2)-z*b/2 = 0.0
```

**5 - Tokenize expression string and play with expression tokens**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument x = new Argument("x");
Argument y = new Argument("y");
Expression e = new Expression("2*sin(x)+(3/cos(y)-e^(sin(x)+y))+10", x, y);
mXparser.consolePrintTokens( e.getCopyOfInitialTokens() );
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |           2 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |         2.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |           * |           * |           3 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           3 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           4 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           5 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           6 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           7 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           8 |           3 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           1 |         3.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           9 |           / |           / |           4 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          10 |         cos |         cos |           2 |           4 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          11 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          12 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          13 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          14 |           - |           - |           2 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          15 |           e |           e |           2 |           9 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          16 |           ^ |           ^ |           5 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          17 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          18 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          19 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          20 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          21 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          22 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          23 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          24 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          25 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          26 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          27 |          10 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |        10.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**6 - You can find much more in** [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/), [mXparser math collection](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-math-collection/) and [mXparser API definition](http://mathparser.org/api/).

**7 - mXparser supports:**

- JAVA
- .NET/MONO
- .NET Core
- .NET Standard
- .NET PCL
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS

Additionally - this software is using mXparser as well - you can learn the syntax [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro).

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

**Taken from [here](https://medium.com/@stoopidguy1992/how-to-write-a-math-expression-parser-in-javascript-b5147bc9466b) [But, I've added the Division(/) functionality to it]**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>how to write a parser - part2 </h1>
    Expression<input id='expression'>
    Result<input id='result'>
    <button onclick="parse()">PARSE</button>
</body>
<script>
    // split expression by operator considering parentheses
    const split = (expression, operator) => {
        const result = [];
        let braces = 0;
        let currentChunk = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < expression.length; ++i) {
            const curCh = expression[i];
            if (curCh == '(') {
                braces++;
            } else if (curCh == ')') {
                braces--;
            }
            if (braces == 0 && operator == curCh) {
                result.push(currentChunk);
                currentChunk = "";
            } else currentChunk += curCh;
        }
        if (currentChunk != "") {
            result.push(currentChunk);
        }
        return result;
    };
// Division
    const parseDivisionSeparatedExpression = (expression) => {
        const numbersString = split(expression, '/');
        const numbers = numbersString.map(noStr => {
            if (noStr[0] == '(') {
                const expr = noStr.substr(1, noStr.length - 2);
                // recursive call to the main function
                return parsePlusSeparatedExpression(expr);
            }
            return noStr;
        });
        const initialValue = 1.0;
        const result = numbers.reduce((acc, no) => {
            return acc / no
        });
        return result;
    };
    var res = (12 - 5-(5/2 + (32 + 4)) + (3*20))/2//12-5-38.5+60
    // this will only take strings containing * operator [ no + ]
    const parseMultiplicationSeparatedExpression = (expression) => {
        const numbersString = split(expression, '*');
        const numbers = numbersString.map(noStr => parseDivisionSeparatedExpression(noStr));

        const initialValue = 1.0;
        console.log("parseMultiplicationSeparatedExpression - numbers: ", numbers)
        const result = numbers.reduce((acc, no) => acc * no, initialValue);
        return result;
    };
    // both * -
    const parseMinusSeparatedExpression = (expression) => {
        const numbersString = split(expression, '-');
        const numbers = numbersString.map(noStr => parseMultiplicationSeparatedExpression(noStr));
        const initialValue = numbers[0];
        const result = numbers.slice(1).reduce((acc, no) => acc - no, initialValue);
        return result;
    };
    // * - +
    const parsePlusSeparatedExpression = (expression) => {
        const numbersString = split(expression, '+');
        const numbers = numbersString.map(noStr => parseMinusSeparatedExpression(noStr));
        const initialValue = 0.0;
        const result = numbers.reduce((acc, no) => acc + no, initialValue);
        return result;
    };
    const parse = () => {
        const expressionNode = document.getElementById('expression');
        const resultNode = document.getElementById('result');
        var expression = expressionNode.value;
        expression = expression.replace(/ +/g, '')
        console.log("parse - expression: ", expression)
        const result = parsePlusSeparatedExpression(expression, '+');
        resultNode.value = String(result);
    };
</script>
```

**Example:** 12 * 5+(5 * (32 - 4)) + 3 = 203