# How to evaluate math expression in matched result of a regular expression in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a problem about regular expressions. I wonder is it possible to evaluate a math expression on the matched result of a regular expression in powershell? I can't use powershell to evaluate it, only must regex.

Problem Statement:

I have a code something like following:

```
$id = $reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
$col1 = $reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
$col2 = $reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
$col3 = $reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
$col4 = $reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
$col5 = $reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
$col6 = $reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
$col7 = $reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
...
```

I need to increase by 3 indexes 0, 1, 2, etc. in GetValue() text with Find & Replace dialog of Powershell ISE.

Result should be like that:

```
$id = $reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
$col1 = $reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
$col2 = $reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
$col3 = $reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
$col4 = $reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
$col5 = $reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
$col6 = $reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
$col7 = $reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
...
```

I was try

```
Find what: GetValue\((\d)\)
Replace with: GetValue($1+3)
```

But I couldn't success, and I couldn't find any document or reasonable solution about the problem.

Very thanks in advance for any possible solution.

Comment: Refactor your code to use an array for the left hand side and a loop and you won't need to  do fancy regex to change the starting index

Comment: For parsing mathematical infix notation, see earlier [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2969561/503046).

Comment: Did the answer below help? Please let know if you need more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not satisfy my question, because i want to make it with regex. Actually i look for an answer it is possible or not with "only" regex (in 'replace with' part). If there is a way what it is. I also can't still found a solution.

Comment: Which code editor are you using?

Comment: @Mark I'm using Powershell ISE.

Comment: I know a solution for **vscode**, `FInd and Transform` an extension I wrote can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
PS> $s = '$col1 = $reader.GetValue(1).ToString();'
PS> $rx = [regex]'(?<=GetValue\()\d+(?=\))'
PS> $rx.Replace($s, { param($m) [int]$m.Value + 1 })
$col1 = $reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
```

*Details*:

- The regex pattern is compiled as a regex object here
- The pattern is re-written to only consume one or more digits, the rest is wrapped with non-consuming lookarounds (a `(?<=GetValue\()` is a positive lookbehind and `(?=\))` is a positive lookahead) so that further match manipulation could be simpler
- The `Regex.Replace` method with match evaluator is used, and the `{ param($m) [int]$m.Value + 1 }` part takes the match value (what `\d+` matches), casts the string to integer value, adds `1` and the result is put back instead of the digits consumed.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DGetValue%5C%28%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5C%29%29&i=%24id%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%280%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col1%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%281%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col2%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%282%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col3%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%283%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col4%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%284%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col5%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%285%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col6%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%286%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24col7%20%3D%20%24reader.GetValue%287%29.ToString%28%29%3B%0D%0A...). *Details*:

- `(?<=GetValue\()` - immediately to the left of the current location, there must be `GetValue(` text
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=\))` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be a `)` char.